# slackr_history error (Error in rename(., channel = "id") ) R

Tags: r, slack-api

Library slackr.

language R.

My task , take data from slack and try convert data from some slack channel  (history of messages) to DF and build Dashboard, but have problem with 1 moment

If i use function slackr_history i add params:

```
slackr_history_test(
message_count = 100,
channel = "name",
token = "token",
posted_to_time = as.numeric(Sys.time()),
duration = NULL,
posted_from_time = 0,
paginate = FALSE,
inclusive = TRUE
)
```

After run i have error

```
Error in `rename()`:
! Can't rename columns that don't exist.
✖ Column `id` doesn't exist.
Backtrace:
  1. global slackr_history_test(...)
 11. dplyr:::rename.data.frame(., channel = "id")
```

Try to replase 1 topic in function

```
if (!paginate) {
  resp <- call_slack_api(
    "/api/conversations.history",
    .method = GET,
    token = token,
    channel = channel,
    latest = posted_to_time,
    oldest = posted_from_time,
    inclusive = inclusive,
    limit = message_count
  )


  resp <- dplyr::rename(resp, c("channel" = "id"))

  resp <- convert_response_to_tibble(resp, "messages")
} else {

}
  }

  resp
```

This topic must help me , but no